# crashlytics custom crash reporting not showing on Firebase Console

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

so I'm using this tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports to enable crashlytics crash report in my Android App. I noticed that Custom Crashes never appears on my Firebase Console using this code:

```
Crashlytics.log(Log.DEBUG, "tag", "message");
```

After setting my UserIdentifier.
But when I tried Forcing a crash like this:

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().crash(); // Force a crash
```

it appears on my Dashboard. So why is my Custom Crash missing.

When I switched back to custom logging, It never works. I also tried using LogException, that didn't work as well.

```
Crashlytics.log(Log.ASSERT, TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
Crashlytics.logException(e);
```

Please note that It's Firebase console I'm using.

Comment: Please refer to this answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/58569022/2768515

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Firebase here.

`Crashlytics.log(Log.DEBUG, "tag", "message");` will log information into a crash, but the logs are only sent and processed **if a crash or non-fatal exception happens** in the same session of the app.

Writing the log is done async, and we focus on capturing crashes or non-fatal exceptions over writing the log to disk. If the log happens just before a crash or non-fatal as in this example:

`Crashlytics.log(Log.ASSERT, TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
Crashlytics.logException(e);`

It's possible we didn't have time to write the log before the exception happened. In that case, we'd prioritize capturing the exception believing that getting the exception or crash is more important then a log.

Comment: I have integrated firebase SDK in one of my App(IOS) and i'm able to see only the sample crash which is provided by you but remaining crashes not at all capturing.Can you please help me on this.